# How do I use if/else in a generic function? C#

Tags: c#

First I'd like to say that im pretty new in regards to coding, so don't kill me if the code looks horrible.

Alright, so the problem is that im trying to make a generic function which purpose is to take two sorted arrays and merge them into a new sorted array.
The problem im facing is trying to use if's in the function, and it doesn't let me use the `<` operand.

```
public object[] mergeTwoSorted<Tone, Ttwo>(Tone[] array, Ttwo[] array2)
{
    object[] mergedArray = new object[array.Length + array2.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array is ValueType && array2 is ValueType)
        {
            if (array[i] > array2[i])

        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: This is a common problem, `ValueType` does not imply it is numeric, nor that you can compare with `>`. This seems like a problem you can solve another way. Maybe add what you're *actually* trying to achieve (rather than how you're trying to achieve it) and you'll get some better guidance. Another point is how would this behave if, for eaxmple `Tone` is an array of ints and `Ttwo` is an array of Monkeys

Comment: You want to compare two different types

Comment: And also, you're checking `array is ValueType`, which is always `false`, regardless of the type of elements contained in the array. The array itself is always a reference type.

Comment: What are the types in these sorted arrays? `Tone`/`Ttwo`, are they the actual types or are we talking primitives here? How are the types sorted in the arrays (what are you using to compare... e.g. `IComparable`?)

Comment: Charleh - the types can be any type, which is why I want  this function to be generic. Also thank you all for the help. I haven't give much thought about what sorted means if the type of the array isn't a value type.. The problem is this: "Write a function that merges two sorted lists into a new sorted list. [1,4,6],[2,3,5] → [1,2,3,4,5,6]. You can do this quicker than concatenating them followed by a sort."

I use arrays since I don't know much about lists...

Comment: To compare object you need the class to inherit ICompare.  An array of object doesn't know how to do the comparison.  The string and int types do know how to compare.  Your issue is you are using the object type which is giving an issue.

Comment: So what you want is two arrays of two different types, but with an ordering relationship between the types, merged into an array of objects? That is... a bit odd, but certainly possible. Can you say more about why you want to do this?

Comment: This is what I want. I chose the object type since it can hold all types inside it (correct me if I'm wrong). The reason is very simple... I'm trying to be a better programmer ^_^"

Comment: Based on the problem statement you've shown in the comments, I think you are expected to assume that the data is `int`s, there's no reason for generics here.

Comment: Rotem - but I want to make it generic! What is the point otherwise... :)

Comment: You're missing the point of my question. **Are there two different types here or not**?  Are you merging a sorted array of giraffes with a sorted array of apples, is the question.

Comment: Sounds like the point is that you understand how you can make it faster than concatenating and then sorting. If you make it generic, I would at the very least stick to the same type for both arrays. boxing to `object` is useless here. What use it the resulting merged array to anyone?

Comment: If the two arrays are always of the same type then **do not make two type parameters** and **do not use object**.  If the two input arrays are both the same type, just call that type T, and then the output array is also T.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First I'd like to say that im pretty new in regards to coding, so don't kill me if the code looks horrible.

It looks pretty reasonable so far. It looks like what you're trying to do is to take two *sorted* arrays of two *different* types, but there is an ordering relationship between the two types. You're then *merging* the two arrays into an array of objects, such that the objects from the two arrays are still in the same order, but they are interleaved with each other to match the inter-type ordering relation, yes?

That is an unusual thing to do, but it is possible.

**If that is not what you are doing, then you need to stop and re-design the code**.  In particular, if your intention is to take two arrays of the *same* type, then you must have *one* type parameter, not *two*, and you must make an array of `T` as the output, not `object`.

The problem is that there is in general no way to express "I have an ordering relationship between these two types" in C#. You'll have to provide a function that does that.  Traditionally we provide a function that takes the two types and returns an integer: -1 if the first is the smaller, 1 if the second is the smaller, and 0 if they are equal.

If we have that then your method becomes:

```
public static object[] MergeTwoSorted<TOne, TTwo> (
  TOne[] items1, 
  TTwo[] items2,
  Func<TOne, TTwo, int> comparer) 
{
```

Note that we are using standard C# conventions here. Methods begin with a capital, type parameters are `TSomething`, and so on.  A `Func<A, B, C>` is a function that takes an `A`, a `B`, and returns a `C`.  Methods that do not manipulate an instance of their class are `static`.

Note that there is no need to re-state in the name of a thing what its type is.  Say what the thing is *logically*, not *how it is stored*:

```
    object[] merged = new object[items1.Length + items2.Length];
```

Now your loop needs some work:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array is ValueType && array2 is ValueType)
        {
            if (array[i] > array2[i])
```

Arrays are never value types. I think you do not understand the difference between values and references, and *that is really important to understand*, so do some research on that.

Also, you have a counter `i` which counts the *big merged array*, but you use that as an index into the *small arrays*.  That is very wrong; do you see why?

Think about it this way: you are going to count through both arrays at the same time filling in the merged array. So that would be:

```
int current1 = 0;
int current2 = 0;
while (current1 + current2 < merged.Length)
{
  if (comparer(items1[current1], items2[current2]) < 0)
  {
    // items1[current1] is the smaller
    merged[current1+current2] = items1[current1];
    current1 += 1;
  }
  else
  {
```

**There is a bug in the code above; can you find it?** Hint: indices for all array accesses must be `>= 0` and `< Length` of the array.  Is there a way in the code I've written so far that this gets violated?

- Can you fix the bug and finish it off?
- Can you now make a call site that takes an array of strings, an array of numbers, and an ordering relationship between strings and numbers, and merges the arrays?

Comment: First of all, thank you for the comperhensive reply. I don't understand why you mean by "inter-type ordering relation". Let's say I have a list of chars {a,b,c} and ints {1,2,3}. I fail to see a relationship between them, unless we say a is the first letter of the alphabet, so it is comparable to 1, which is the start of all positive numbers.

Comment: @GilShvarzman: You keep on not answering the important question I'm asking you. **Why are there two type parameters `TOne` and `TTwo`?** This mean that there are *two arrays* of *two different types* that you are trying to merge, and they can be *any types*.  You have a sorted array of newspapers and a sorted array of turtles, and you wish to merge them together. **That means that there must be a way to tell whether a given newspaper is smaller than a given turtle**. You must have an *inter-type ordering relation*.  Again **if that is not your scenario then do not make two type parameters**.

Comment: @GilShvarzman: If you want to merge two arrays of the *same* type then the signature must be `public static T[] Merge<T>(T[] items1, T[] item2)`, and you can then make a constraint of `IComparable<T>` on `T` to indicate that a T may be ordered with respect to another T.

Comment: @GilShvarzman: I strongly suspect that you are attempting to run before you walk here.  **Designing generic algorithms is what you should do after you have mastered designing non-generic algorithms**.  If you cannot write the code *perfectly* for ints, and doubles, and strings, all individually, then you will not be successful writing a generic implementation.

Comment: The reason I wrote 2 parameters Tone and Ttwo is because the function is supposed to merge them. They can be of any type indeed. I understand now what you mean by relationship, although I don't think I am able to implement it.
A little above my current level perhaps. :\

Comment: @GilShvarzman: You're still not answering my question: can they be of *different* types? Where are you getting this problem from in the first place? This is a very strange problem. I do not understand why you think you need two type parameters here. **That is the choice that is making this problem hard**, so I do not understand why you chose it.

Comment: @GilShvarzman: Regardless though **you should first write a correct merge sort of arrays of integers**.  You will not be successful writing generic sorting algorithms if you cannot be successful writing non-generic sorting algorithms.

Comment: They can be different, yes. I did write a function for integers.

Answer (score -3):

```
public static object[] mergeTwoSorted<Tone, Ttwo>(Tone[] array, Ttwo[] array2)  
    where Tone : IComparable<Ttwo> 
{
    var mergedArray = new object[array.Length + array2.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array is ValueType && array2 is ValueType)
        {
            if (array[i].CompareTo( array2[i] )>0)

        }
    }
    return mergedArray;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

If you want to use specific operations on Generics, you have to limit them with a where clause accordingly. As when working with Fractural Numebrs, you need a common denominator.

Something like a "IMergable" interface that you have to write yourself.

```
public IMergeable[] mergeTwoSorted<Tone, Ttwo> (Tone[] array, Ttwo[] array2)
    where Tone : IMergeable, Ttwo : IMergeable
    {
        IMergeable[] mergedArray = new IMergeable[array.Length + array2.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array is ValueType && array2 is ValueType)
            {
                if (array[i] > array2[i])

            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could jsut use one type:

```
public Tone[] mergeTwoSorted<Tone> (Tone[] array, Tone[] array2)
        {
            IMergeable[] mergedArray = new IMergeable[array.Length + array2.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < mergedArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array is ValueType && array2 is ValueType)
                {
                    if (array[i] > array2[i])

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: 1) You mention an `IMergeable` interface but don't define it and don't use it in the code, instead using `>` 2) You check `array is ValueType` which is always `false`.

Comment: I hope this doesn't come off as offensive, it's meant to be constructive, but perhaps others believe that if you haven't taken the time to try to run your method and see if it works before posting it then they shouldn't take the time to give you specific feedback.